# How to use Address function to select a cell with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

So I currently have a formula set up using =ADDRESS() to return a cell based on some inputs. This gives back the cell address as text in the formula cell.
Basically I need to use the cell address that is found as a range to select that cell with ActiveCell. in VBA. Is this possible?

Comment: `Set RangeFromFormula = Range(CelllWhereFormulaComputed.Value)`

Comment: `Range(Range("A1").Value).Select`  But there are many better easier ways to do this.

Answer (score 0):

This code will select the range whose address is in cell A1 whenever a) the sheet recalculates and b) the address has changed since the last recalculation. You may need to tweak this to get the reselection to happen only when you want it to. Generally, using programmatic reselection is not advisable as it is quite difficult to control and can be very irritating to the user.

```
Option Explicit
    
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    '// This code is triggered whenever the sheet recalculates
    '// It checks if the range address stored in cell [A1] has changed
    '// as a result of recalculation, and if so selects that range

    Static prevAddress As String

    Debug.Print "Calculate was called"

    If [A1].Value <> prevAddress Then
        On Error Resume Next
        Range([A1].Value).Select
        If Err.Number = 0 Then
            prevAddress = [A1].Value
            Debug.Print ActiveCell.Address + " was selected"
            '// call function that uses activeCell here.....
        End If
    End If



End Sub
```